# Visual Studio 2010 statement completion IME?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am having a very odd problem with Visual Studio 2010. After using it for a while, the statement completion comes up in what looks like a vertical IME mode. Nothing I type ever gets to the document, hitting esc gets rid of the box, but any typing brings it right back up. Restarting VS fixes it for a while.

I have uninstalled all languages besides english and set my international settings to english. I have even turned off intellisense and statement completion, still get it.

A picture is worth a thousand words:
[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/143346/VS2010_IME.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/143346/VS2010_IME.png)

Comment: Try disabling the Language Bar.  It is sensitive to the kind of shortcut key strokes you'd use in Visual Studio.

Comment: language bar has not been on at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I fixed it, looking at the keyboard settings, a Chinese keyboard was installed and a short cut was defined to switch between languages (left alt+shift), which presumably I was hitting.

Removed all keyboards but english, turned off the shortcut key and rebooted for it to take effect.

Interesting what comes preinstalled...